# Bulk Record Insert

Tags: asp-classic, bulkinsert

I need to fetch data from one table (multiple rows) and insert into other table after modifying and adding some new fields.

For example:

**Table 1**
itemid,
price,
qnt,
date_of_dispatch

**Table2**
Invoiceid,
Invoicedate,
customer_id,
itemid,
price,
qnt,
total_amt,
date_of_dispatch,
grandtotal

Please help me to make it in asp with ms access

Comment: What you have so far? Are you familiar with `ADODB.Connection` and SQL statements like `SELECT` and `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: I am able to fetch data and show in text boxes using while loop , but not able to insert in other table.
and yes I have some knnowledge of sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the records one by one in the loop over the records from the first table:

```
Dim oConn1
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "connection string here"
Set oRS = oConn.Execute("Select * From Table1")
Do Until oRS.EOF
    strItemId = oRS("item_id")
    strPrice = oRS("price")
    '....get more data
    '....also add new fields like:
    Invoicedate = Date()
    customer_id = 500
    '.......
    If Request("confirm_" & strItemId)="1" Then
        strSQL = "Insert Into Table2 (itemid, price, customer_id, ...) Values ('" & strItemId & "', '" & strPrice & ', ..."
        oConn.Execute(strSQL)
        Response.Write("Item " & strItemId & " inserted<br />")
    Else  
        Response.Write("Confirm insert of item " & strItemId & " <input type=""checkbox"" name=""confirm_" & strItemId & """ value=""1"" />")
    End If
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
```

This is the basic approach, hope it's clear enough.

Edit: added support on confirming every record - now checkbox will appear for each record, and only if the checkbox will be Checked the INSERT statement will take place. This is taking each `item_id` as some sort of "key" you can use any other unique value as well.

Comment: HI,
Yes this is best basic aproach , but we cant use insert in first time, beacuse first we have to display all the records and give option to user to do some correction if needed, then finally we can go for save the data.
I hope you got me.