# Batch data insert

Tags: asp-classic, bulkinsert

I need to fetch data from one table (multiple rows) and insert into other table after modifying and adding some new fields.

For example:

> Table 1 itemid, price, qnt,
>   date_of_dispatch
>
> Table2 Invoiceid, Invoicedate,
>   customer_id, itemid, price, qnt,
>   total_amt, date_of_dispatch,
>   grandtotal

Please help me to make it in asp with ms access
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467708

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the input type with the same name, so you can collect an array with all the values.

Sample:

```
<form ...>
   <input type="text" name="InvoiceDate" ..>

   <table>
   <thead>
         ....
   <thead>
   <tbody>
   <% do while not rsItems.EOF %>
    <tr>
       <input type="hidden" name="ItemID" value="<%= trim( rsItems("itemID") ) %>">
       <td><input type="text" name="Product" value="<%= rsItems("Product") %>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Price" value="<%= rsItems("Price") %>"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Qnt" value="<%= rsItems("qnt")%>"></td>
    </tr>
    <% rs.movenext %>
   <% loop %>
```

Then, when processing the form:

```
for i = 1 to request.form("ItemID").count
   ThisItemProduct = request.form("Product")(i)
   ThisItemPrice = request.form("Price")(i)
   ...
```

You can work the details.